# Why does this C program generate SIGPIPE later than expected?

Tags: c, sigpipe

This program generates `SIGPIPE` after piping it to "`head -n 1`", after a random time. I understand that because we're feeding more to "`head -n 1`" after the first line, we would expect it to generate `SIGPIPE`, but instead it will make it to a random number (usually > 20 and < 200) before exitting. Any idea why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
  int i;
  char *s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\n";

  i = 0;
  while (1) {
    fputs(s, stdout);
    fflush(stdout);
    fprintf(stderr, "Iteration %d done\n", i);
    i++;
  }
}
```

This is not homework, just something in my professor's notes that I do not understand.

Comment: Ehm, **`const`** `char *s = ...`

Comment: It takes time to stuff the tobacco.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the vagaries of scheduling.

Your producer — let's call it `alphabeta` — is able to run for some amount time before `head` is able to read and exit (thus breaking the pipe).

That "some amount of time", of course, is variable.

Sometimes `alphabeta` runs 20 times before `head` can read stdin and exit.  Sometimes 200 times.  On my system, sometimes 300 or 1000 or 2000 times.  Indeed, it can theoretically loop up to the capacity of the pipe connecting producer and consumer.

For demonstration, let's introduce some delay so we can be reasonably sure that `head` is stuck in a read() before `alphabeta` produces a single line of output:

```
so$ { sleep 5; ./alphabeta; } | head -n 1
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
Iteration 0 done
```

(N.B. it's not guaranteed that `alphabeta` will only iterate once in the above.  However, *on an unloaded system*, this is more-or-less always going to be the case:  `head` will be ready, and its read/exit will happen more-or-less immediately.)

Watch instead what happens when we artificially delay `head`:

```
so$ ./alphabeta | { sleep 2; head -n 1; }
Iteration 0 done
...
Iteration 2415 done    # <--- My system *pauses* here as pipe capacity is reached ...
Iteration 2416 done    # <--- ... then it resumes as head completes its first read()
...
Iteration 2717 done    # <--- pipe capacity reached again; head didn't drain the pipe 
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

As an aside, @R.. is quite right in his remarks that SIGPIPE is synchronous.  In your case, the first fflush-induced write to a broken pipe (after `head` has exited) will synchronously generate the signal.  This is [documented behavior](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fflush.html).

Answer (score 4):

I think it is simply because signals are asynchronous.

Update: As others pointed out they (more precisely many, including SIGPIPE) are not. This was an unthoughtful answer :)

Comment: SIGPIPE is a synchronous signal.

Comment: @R.. `stdio` doesn't buffer past an `fflush`.

Comment: Not this process's stdio. `head`'s.

Answer (score 0):

Socket writes are buffered and asynchronous, so you won't generally get an error arising from a specific write until a following read or writ).

Comment: I'm not sure why socket writes are material to a question about piped output.

Answer (score 0):

The `head` command is using stdio to read stdin and thus the first getc does not return until the buffer is full or EOF, whichever happens first.

Comment: You can verify this with strace.

Comment: No, it's pipe capacity and scheduling.  See my answer.

Comment: As pilcrow said, it's scheduling.  The kernel's pipe buffer (typically 64-128 KiB) not filling up in this instance, since only about 200*27 = 5.4 KB of data is getting written.

Comment: Indeed, that's correct. The `read` in `head` does not block until it fills the buffer; it returns immediately if there is some data available.